# Name-value pair list with duplicate names to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

For submitting the form data to the server from the AJAX call to bind Telerik MVC grid, we can set e.data in [OnDataBinding](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#OnDataBinding) event to a anonymous JavaScript object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Grid_onDataBinding(e) {
     var categoryValue = "Beverages";
     var priceValue = 3.14;

     // pass additional values by setting the "data" field of the event argument
     e.data = { 
        // the key ("category") specifies the variable name of the action method which will contain the specified value
        category: categoryValue,
        price: priceValue
     };
}
</script>
```

To facilitate the model binding for Boolean, `ASP.NET MVC` generates checkboxes along with a hidden text field with the same name

```
<input name="myCheckBox" class="check-box" id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" value="true"/>
<input name="myCheckBox" type="hidden" value="false"/>
```

and when these are submitted the data submitted is

`myCheckBox=true&MyCheckBox=false` - when the checkbox is checked

`myCheckBox=false` - when the checkbox is not checked

For pages where there is no checkbox, the post data can be easily obtained by

```
e.data = form.serializeObject()
```

where [serializeObject](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject) creates that object by looping thru all the form fields. How to construct that object in case of forms when there are checkboxes as described above? Basically how can a name-value pair list be represented in the object form when the names are allowed to be duplicate?

```
e.data = { 
    textBox1: "some value1",
    myCheckBox: true //,
    //myCheckBox: false // ???
};
```

The implementation of [serializeObject](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject) creates an array for such form elements and those are submitted as `myCheckBox[]=true&myCheckBox[]=false` which breaks the model binding on the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select specific form subelements to serialize, rather than just serializing the entire form. This allows you to filter out the ones you don't want:

```
$('form input:not([type=hidden])').serializeObject();
```

**Edit**: Per @amit_g's comment, you want the checkbox when it's checked or the hidden element when it's not. This requires a more complex filter than the `:not` selector:

```
$('form input')
    .filter(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'hidden') {
            // filter out those with checked checkboxes
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            return !$('form input[type=checkbox][name=' + name +']')
                .prop('checked');
        } else {
            // include all other input
            return true;
        }
    })
    .serializeObject();
```

See the working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/nzmg7/4/

Comment: Sure, but that breaks the very reason, MVC framework puts those fields to begin with. The browser doesn't submit those checkboxes that are not selected, and that is when these hidden fields are used by the framework for model binding.

Answer (score 0):

serializeObject uses [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) internally and [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) serializes only those elements that would be submitted actually. So using the following code, I have disabled the hidden fields corresponding to checkbox and added a change event to toggle the disbaled state on each hidden input. Since the inputs are disabled, they don't get serialized.

> The .serializeArray() method uses the standard W3C rules for
>   successful controls to determine which elements it should include; in
>   particular the element cannot be disabled and must contain a name
>   attribute. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not
>   submitted using a button. Data from file select elements is not
>   serialized.

```
$('form.form-class :checkbox').change(function () {
    enableDisableCorrespondingHiddenField($(this));
});

$('form.form-class :checkbox').each(function () {
    enableDisableCorrespondingHiddenField($(this));
});

enableDisableCorrespondingHiddenField(checkbox) {
    $(":hidden[name='" + checkbox.attr("name") + "']", checkbox.parent()).attr("disabled", checkbox.attr("checked"));
}
```